# In-app Twitter timeline without authentication?

Tags: android, authentication, twitter, feed, timeline

Lately, I have been working on an app to see if I could do some stuff like a Twitter timeline correctly.

I created a nice little ListView, let some options link to a site, let one option call a Dialog to choose a Twitter account, and accomplished a Twitter feed viewer.

However, it doesn't seem to be possible to actually retrieve a user's timeline without authentication with Twitter? Or is it possible? If so, how do I do that?

Can I retrieve and display a user's Twitter feed without authentication, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can either use the twitter search API, which returns json formatted data, which you must parse, just search the documentation. Alternatively, you can use a direct link to a user's timeline like so:

```
https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/user.json
```

EDIT: This returns the response as .json for me, next it needs to be parsed. Make sure you are parsing the response AFTER it has been received, it looks like you are starting the request and then jumping to parsing it, before the request is complete.

```
public ArrayList<Tweet> getTweets(String Account, int page) {
        String accountUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=@" 
                            + Account + "&rpp=100&page=" + page;


        ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();


        HttpClient client = new  DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(accountUrl);


        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();


        String responseBody = null;
        try{
            responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
            Toast.makeText(this, responseBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // parse response, return arraylist
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


}
```

Comment: Tried to do that, though that doesn't work. 
I am using the Twitter API to enter a link like that one, with the user as a variable. I then parse the JSON data and display it to the user.

The project started throwing errors, if I remember correctly. I will try again and come back here tomorrow, as I'm not at home right now. Busy times :P.

Comment: Still not working, but I have no idea why. Could you take a look at my code?

It's at this link (comments are too small here, I have no GitHub or anything like that):
http://www.androidworld.nl/forum/android-development/26675-update-viewpager-app-voor-school-post273512.html#post273512

Comment: No go still. LogCat is giving me a NullPointerException at `Arraylist<Tweet> tweets = getTweets(Account, 1);`
and at `for(Object t: arr)  {`.

Comment: There can be concurrency issues or possibly you need to add the internet permission to the manifest.

Comment: I hadn't added the Permission yet, always forget those things... Let's see if it works :).

Edit: Nope, still not working.

The code that makes a Dialog to choose an account and calls the Twitter Activity:
http://www.androidworld.nl/forum/android-development/26675-update-viewpager-app-voor-school-6.html#post273512

Comment: Try to put your code that uses responseBody in the try - catch block it is initialized in, not outside of it, then it should work. If it is outside, responseBody has probably not yet been initialized, as network tasks might take a longer time.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation and I'll take a look at it tomorrow (busy day once more ;)).

Comment: Nope, still the same error: http://i1199.photobucket.com/albums/aa477/bassie-1995/Knipsel-5.png

Comment: I guess you must first see if you can output the response in a Toast or in logcat, if you get something, then it should be no big problem to go from there.

Comment: I'll see if I can do this sometime soon. I just got effectively pulled from the project, so it's not that big of a deal right now...